# Show that a set of sequences is open and closed on box topology

Tags: general-topology, box-topology

I have the following question on topology:

> Let $\mathbb R^\mathbb N = \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb R$ with the box topology.
> Show that for all $\bar x = \langle x_n \rangle_n$, the set $ A = \{\bar y :\langle x_n -y_n\rangle_n \to_{n \to \infty} 0  \} $ is open and closed.

I first tried to show that the set is open by showing that $A$ is a neighborhood of all $y\in A$, by showing that there exist open sets $V_i \subseteq \mathbb R$ such that 
$$
\bar y \in \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}V_i \subseteq A
$$
but I'm not really sure if this is the right way. I would like some help or some guidance because this whole box/product topology doesn't sit right with me. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have problems in showing it is closed or open ?

Comment: Both. I assume that it is the same deal with $A^c$ for the closed case, or maybe there is something better here that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, finding these $V_i$ is the easiest way to show openness of $A$; it shows $y \in A$ is an interior point of $A$, for any such $y$.

Try $V_i = (y_i - \frac1i, y_i + \frac1i)$ e.g.

The closedness can also easily be shown by showing the openness of $A^\complement$ in a similar way.

Comment: The question is, what are those $V_i$? I assume that the convergence of $(x_n-y_n)_n$ has a role here, maybe something with open intervals? my mind is blank here.

Comment: Maybe I can use the sets: $V_i = (x_i - \epsilon , x_i + \epsilon)$, but what about the remaining open sets? Because the limit definition tells us that there exists a natural $N$ such that $|x_n - y_n| < \epsilon$ for all $n>N$, so what can we say for $V_1 ,..., V_N$?

Comment: @LagrangeLover you can take them to be suitable open intervals in $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb R$ itself, sometimes (if youdon't care what happens in that coordinate). You have to wonder: what does the convergence of $x_n - y_n$ mean for $y$? Recall that $x$ is a fixed and given point.

Comment: Ok I think I'm done with openness, but with closeness, I think maybe $V_i = (x_i , x_i + 2\epsilon )$. am I getting it right?

Comment: @LagrangeLover $y$ in $A^\complement$ means what? Can you preserve that by suitable $V_i$?

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you very much!